# Receiving error when trying to delete multiple folders inside subfolder using Delete activity in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am receving following error when I try to delete multiple folders which are 7 days older (folder names are dates).
{
"errorCode": "3701",
"message": "Failed to execute delete activity with data source 'AzureBlobFS' and error 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict''. For details, please reference log file here: .",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "Delete1",
"details": []
}
My piplelien looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYtXN.png)

I went through all the access roles for the storage account. I have a contributor access for the storage accont